# Java maven build jar for different environment configuration settings

Tags: java, maven, jar, environment-variables

I have a pure java project built with maven

This java project is using external DB so there's a DB IP & DB username and password.

These values currently are hardcoded. I want to be able to make these values configurable based on the environment.

For example if I want to build the jar for Dev env I will have these values

```
DB IP : 123
DB username : dev123
DB password : dev123
```

for QA

```
DB IP : 345
DB username : Qa123
DB password : Qa123
```

and so on ..

I have looked into the profiles but as I understood I cannot access these values withing my program or it's not recommended to use them for this purpose.

I had experience with Django and I know that we can create `.env` file
and for `.net` we can have what is called `appsettings`.

Thanks.

Comment: Create 1 config jar per env. At runtime, add the jar to the classpath that matches the env.

Comment: Either create an appropriate configuration file which will be put on the class path during runtime so you can control by your classpath at runtime which configuration you are picking up... or just use access to environment variables... never package the configuration into your application...keep the appliation and configuration like a db etc. independent.

Comment: @khmarbaise can you share any resource that might help me on this? cause everything is new to me

Comment: @Michael what do you mean by config jar? what does kind of files is in there to bundle? if you have a helpful resource please share